# jQuery - possible to resize background-image to a set size?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm in a situation where I urgently need to fit a background image of a div to a certain size. Does anyone know if this is possible with jQuery? I know the size it needs to be, it doesn't have to resize with the size of the div. 35,000 images have been scaled to the wrong size and it needs to go live so resizing the images isn't an option!

Any advice appreciated!

EDIT: I'm just seeing whether we're able to alter the HTML to take the background image out of the DIV and put it in a separate absolutely positioned div at the same with an IMG tag in it... the IMG tag can then be resized with CSS.

Comment: Is a complete image or you use 'background' properties on CSS to draw it? (i.e. background-repeat)

Comment: It's a complete image that needs to sit in the middle of the DIV.

Comment: you can specify height/width within the <image> html tag that will size it to your absolute size. Could you also perhaps setup a photoshop action and just run a batch on those 35k images? Might take a day :)

Comment: The original lot were done in a photoshop action, but at 300dpi. I always hated images clearly resized with HTML and wondered what people were thinking... now I find myself complicit.

Comment: I honestly think your best course of action is to just run another batch and resize the images properly.  It will save you headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS3 to change the background size. The browsers that have this feature implemented are Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Konqueror and IE9:

```
.myClass
{
    -o-background-size: 200px 50px;
    -webkit-background-size: 200px 50px;
    -khtml-background-size: 200px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 200px 50px;
    background-size: 200px 50px;
}
```

Not sure about the jQuery implementation of background size.

In this case, maybe [this article](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/) will help you.

Comment: And IE9, using the standard `background-size: 200px 50px;`

Comment: @Kyle Your usage of the word "only" gives the reader the impression that the feature is implemented in a minority of browsers, whereas in fact it is implemented in all but one browser.

Comment: ...and `background-size` [has options other than fixed length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: [This compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html#t010) is helpful.

Comment: @josh I use this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets%29

Comment: @Cordial: if this answer turned out helpful, why didn't you accept it? You know, a "thank you" comment is nice and all, but the most common way of expressing gratitude on SO is by upvoting and accepting answers.

Comment: The answer was helpful and appreciated but didn't answer the original question regarding jQuery - I'm not sure of all the etiquette on SO but I upvoted the comment.

Answer (score 3):

With css:

```
#myDiv {
            background: transparent url(../../Images/2.jpg);
            background-size: 400% 400%; 
        }
```

Note that "400% 400%" gives the width and height. Can also use "px" or "em", a combination, auto etc etc. See the CSS3 spec for more of those details: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

With jquery you can change the background-size like so:

```
$('#myDiv').css({
        'background-size': '200% 200%' 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Background images can only be scaled with features in the CSS 3 drafts, which do not yet have wide support in browsers.

JavaScript could parse the CSS, find the background-image, generate a foreground image (`<img>` for it), style it to be absolutely positioned behind the content and scale it … but that is a lot of work.

The *easiest* and most *reliable* solution would be to knock up a quick script using ImageMagick (I'd probably use bash for this, but PHP or any other programming language are options) to programatically resize all 35,000 images on the server. (This might also be to be the fastest approach too).

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [article](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/)

```
 #img.source-image {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;    
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I stumbled across that but it's not really what I was after - it doesn't need to be resizable as such, just resized!

Answer (score 1):

If the background is used as a `background-image`, you can't set them to 100%. This can be found a 1000 times on SO here I think. So that would go into some nightly batch to resize them all.

You could also create some code to put an `<img>` tag inside the div. The image can then be scaled to 100%. To do this, you have to ask things to your CSS, or div like so:

```
$('div.niceImage').each(function()
{
    var imUrl = $(this).style('background-image'); // if not in style itself, we should ask it to the CSS rules. Don't know if jQuery does this for you.
    $(this).prepend('<img style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;" src="' + imUrl + '" />');
});
```

Comment: If we can't get to the HTML this will definitely be the way to go, many thanks for the suggestion!