# div background image

Tags: html, css

i have a div that is 90x110 how do i restrict the background image i need to use to this size? background image is 120x100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the background image will be cropped to the size of your div automatically, in case there's any other content that doesn't stay in, you can always set overflow to hidden in your CSS:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

You can also resize your background images, if there's a need. Please have a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) to see how it can be achieved (there are multiple ways).

Oh, you may also want to have a look at a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713935/jquery-possible-to-resize-background-image-to-a-set-size/4714177#4714177) posted a few hours ago.

Comment: is there noway to scale the image down to match the size of the div?

Comment: it seems I was just adding this information while you were writing the comment :D

Comment: IE6 is pretty much a relic of history, I wouldn't worry much about it. You won't drive at 200 kph in a classic 1920s car, but as long as it takes you to your destination, you can call yourself one hell of a mechanic for keeping it in such good shape. Same with IE6. If the site *works* in IE6, you're doing a great job with it - it doesn't matter it doesn't look the same as in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The div will not grow larger, the only portion of the background image that will be visible will be a 90x110 rectangle.