# How to set width and height in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles, height, width

I have a background image and I am trying to optimize the site by specifying height and width for all images. I cannot figure out how to set width to 450 and height to 350.

```
<!-- BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
    <script src="js/supersized.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$.supersized({slides:[{image:"/images/heritage/background.jpg"}]});});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the width and height for all images, you can use the [`.width()` and `.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/). In your case, you'll want the following code for `<img>` tags:

```
$(img).width(450).height(350)
```

Now, if you're trying to resize background images, you'll need to set CSS styles ([duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713935/jquery-possible-to-resize-background-image-to-a-set-size)):

```
$(selector).css({
    "-o-background-size": 450px 350px,
    "-webkit-background-size": 450px 350px,
    "-khtml-background-size": 450px 350px,
    "-moz-background-size": 450px  350px,
    "background-size": 450px 350px
})
```

**EDIT:** If you want to optimize the image or set width and height attributes to the actual image, try using [resrc.it](http://www.resrc.it/), which offers compression/optimization (through the `O={}` parameter), resizing (through the `S={}` parameter), or cropping through the `C={}` parameter. However, resrc.it is a paid API with a free 30-day trial.

If you're looking for a free option, you'll probably need to host your one on your own server. A good suggestion would be [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/), which has a free version with just the features you need.

You could also either host your site off of Google AppEngine or host your own CDN off of it to utilize their image processing utilities, which take a bit of setup, but work just fine once you've gotten through the hard work.

The [last option](https://carlo.zottmann.org/2013/04/14/google-image-resizer/) is to use a "hidden" service provided by Google, and might be unstable. This option can be accessed using the following url:

https://images1-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy

which takes in the `url`, `container`, `refresh` (cache time), `resize_w`, and `resize_h` as url parameters. I've tested this out and as of now (post time), it still works.

Comment: What I am trying to do is optimize the page.  I run it through http://gtmetrix.com/.  I need to set width and height attributes for the actual .jpg and then I assume supersized will take it from there.

it returns the following error:  The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes:

=>>>http://www.wacoaircraft.net/images/heritage/background.jpg (Dimensions: 450 x 300)

Answer (score 0):

you can use min_height,min_width options , see the [Supersized documentation](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#min_height)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.supersized({
        slides: [{
            image: "/images/heritage/background.jpg",

        }],
min_height:350,
min_width:450
    });
});
```